# Recurrent error 1205:lock wait timeout for any query

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm just getting started on mysql and I downloaded and imported -using MySQL workbench- a database that contains two tables, one (objects) is 460 000 rows and 40 columns large, the other (funding) is 45 000 rows and 15 columns large.
I get the 1205 time out error everytime I launch a query that interacts with the large table.

For example :

```
UPDATE new_schema.cb_funding_rounds
SET category_code =   
(SELECT category_code    
FROM new_schema.cb_objects    
WHERE new_schema.cb_objects.id = new_schema.cb_funding_rounds.object_id) 
WHERE EXISTS   
(SELECT category_code    FROM new_schema.cb_objects    
WHERE new_schema.cb_objects.id = new_schema.cb_funding_rounds.object_id)
```

(trying to fill the column category_code from the 2nd table with the values from the respective elements of the 1st table, I don't even know if the code is correct.)

Or

```
> delete from new_schema.cb_objects where category_code IS NULL;
```

I tried to delay the time out using some suggestions i found like :

```
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1000; 
SET global max_allowed_packet=104857600;
```

But i still get the 1205 error everytime. I killed all sleeping processes.
I am guessing that it's because the database is so large that any query takes too long, but I can't even delete data without timing out.

How can I work around this issue ? What would be the proper query to get the update done, I only need this to be able to use the database. Any suggestion is welcome !

Comment: This happens because your transaction is trying to access a row that is locked by another transaction. Then it waits for the specified time and returns error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

Comment: I don't understand which transaction can be locking the rows. Does the delete transaction lock the rows ? What would be the correct query to get the "copy-paste" operation done ? I know it's very basic but I am stuck and I get this error what ever I do ...

Comment: By the way I only have the error when deleting from the big table. I can delete on the other one without any problem. If the transaction was locking the rows shouldn't I get the error all the time ?